# Закрывается модальное окно

Tags: javascript, input, form, валидация, submit

Помогите пожалуйста, я не сильна в JS. Сделала вот такой код валидации:

```
let form = document.querySelector('.js-form'),
    formInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.js-input');

form.onsubmit = function () {
    let emptyInputs = Array.from(formInputs).filter(input => input.value === '');

    formInputs.forEach(function (input) {
        if (input.value === '') {
            input.classList.add('error');
        } else {
            input.classList.remove('error');
            }
        });
    
    if (emptyInputs.length !== 0) {
        console.log('inputs not filled');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Вся суть в том: если поля заполнены он отправляет форму. А если не заполнены, то не отправляет - НО закрывает модальное окно с формой. Что нужно мне добавить в код, чтобы он не давал закрыть окно с пустыми полями при нажатии кнопки "отправить"?

Модальное окно:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="Order" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
    <form class="form js-form" method="POST" action="./php/telegrambot.php">
        <div class="modal-header bg-danger border-bottom border-primary border-4">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Отправка формы</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
    
        <div class="modal-body bg-light">
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="col-12">
                <label class="form-label"><b>Имя:</b></label>
                <input class="form-control input js-input" maxlength="20" id="FirstNameInput" placeholder="Как к Вам обращаться" name="FirstName">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                <label class="form-label"><b>Контактный номер:</b> 
             </label>
                <input class="form-control input js-input" maxlength="11" id="PhoneInput" placeholder="Ваш телефон для связи" name="Phone">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                        
        <div class="modal-footer bg-danger border-top border-primary border-4">
        <div class="row justify-content-end">
            <div class="col-4 content-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary border-2 text-nowrap me-2" data-bs-toggle="modal">Отправить</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Нужен код открытия/закрытия модального окна

Comment: @humster_spb добавила код модального окна, больше скриптов нет, js код валидации подключается отдельным файлом. Код js выше, больше ничего нет

Comment: @Milena  CSS добавь свой не понимаю о каком модальном окне идет речь

Comment: Вы не всю разметку модального окна привели - судя по тому, что это Бутстрап, там должен быть главный родительский блок `<div class="modal fade" id="MyModal" tabindex="-1">` (id в Вашем случае может быть другим). Так вот в проверке на заполненность полей в случае ошибки добавьте код `$('#MyModal').modal('show')` - тогда по идее окно должно остаться открытым.

Comment: @humster_spb да вы правы, простите пожалуйста, исправила код и добавила три строки = забыла совсем..

Comment: ну вот попробуйте в js добавить код, который я привёл - только вместо #MyModal у Вас #Order

Comment: @humster_spb я должна прописать вот так? if (input.value === '') {
            input.classList.add('error');
            $('#Order').modal('show');

Comment: Да. Я бы только не делал строгое сравнение с типизацией - лучше поставьте ==, вместо === (во всех случаях)

Comment: @humster_spb добавила в тот блок как вы сказали, убрала лишние "=", но всё равно закрывает окно после нажатия на копку(((

Comment: data-bs-toggle="modal" у вас в кнопке добавлен попробуйте убрать это

Comment: @pyduti спасибо огромное, убрала и всё получилось!!

Comment: Ох и костыль вам посоветовали!!! Не делайте так!

Answer (score 0):

Просто уберите с кнопки атрибут `data-bs-toggle="modal"` и закрывайте модальное окно, когда форма успешно отправлена!

```js
let form = document.querySelector('.js-form'),
    formInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.js-input');

form.onsubmit = function () {
    let emptyInputs = Array.from(formInputs).filter(input => input.value === '');

    formInputs.forEach(function (input) {
        if (input.value === '') {
            input.classList.add('error');
        } else {
            input.classList.remove('error');
            }
        });
    
    if (emptyInputs.length !== 0) {
        console.log('inputs not filled');
        return false;
    }
    
    // Если всё хорошо, то закрываем модальное окно
    $('#MyModal').modal('close')
}
```

Это сделать поведение окна контролируемым